# Sony Xperia X on Nougat, Cell Information app won't stay off

Tags: sony-xperia, 7.1-nougat

I recently bought an Xperia X to replace an older sony phone I had.   After getting it set up, there is an application called "Cell Information" that constantly shows in my notification bar.  the only way I can find to turn it off is to go into the application and force quit it, and this works till the next time I restart the device.

In the application settings I can't find any way to disable notifications or turn it off permanently.  This is not a huge issue, just an annoyance.

Does anyone know how to permanently stop this application from showing in the notification bar?